# change button link on click of select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, dropdown

My html code

```
<select>
<option>monthly</option>
<option>annually</option>
<option>triennially</option>
</select>

<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $ButtonLink1; ?>" class="btn"> Get started</a>
</div>
<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $ButtonLink2; ?>" class="btn"> Get started</a>
</div>
<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $ButtonLink3; ?>" class="btn"> Get started</a>
</div>
```

When `monthly` option is selected `div` with `$ButtonLink1` should be visible.

When `annually` option is selected `div` with `$ButtonLink2` should be visible.

When `triennially` option is selected `div` with `$ButtonLink3` should be visible.

Default visible value should be `monthly` option and `div` with `$ButtonLink1`.

Can anyone please tell me how to write script to achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I think that u need something like this, this code add an event on select, this event get the name of button that u need and show.

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
  var buttonId = document.getElementById("select").value;
  var button = document.querySelector('[button="' + buttonId + '"]');
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(el => {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
  button.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
.btn {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
<option value="" selected hidden>Select</option>
<option value="google">monthly</option>
<option value="github">annually</option>
<option value="stack">triennially</option>
</select>

<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="https://github.com" class="btn" button="github"> Get started Git</a>
</div>
<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="https://google.com" class="btn" button="google"> Get started Google</a>
</div>
<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="btn" button="stack"> Get started Stack</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With barely any changes to the HTML you can easily do this by comparing the `selectedIndex` of the `option` in the `select` menu to the index within the nodelist returned by querying the DOM for all nodes with class `pricing-btn`. To ensure that these `pricing-btn` elements are hidden by default except the first set their css display property to `none` and assign a visibility class within the `change` event handler.

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  /* create an array from the nodelist of all `.pricing-btn` div nodes */
  let col=[...document.querySelectorAll('.pricing-btn')];
      /*
        remove the visibility class from ALL nodes in array/nodelist 
      */
      col.forEach(div=>div.classList.remove('viz'));
      
      /* 
        process some of the array until the selected option index matches the array index. 
        Add the visibility class when matched and exit `some` iterator
      */
      col.some((div,i)=>{
        if( i === this.options.selectedIndex - 1 ){
          div.classList.add('viz');
          return true;
         }
      });
});
```

```css
.pricing-btn{display:none;}
.viz{display:block;}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected hidden disabled>Please select
  <option>monthly
  <option>annually
  <option>triennially
</select>

<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="?bttn=1" class="btn viz"> Get started</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="?bttn=2" class="btn"> Get started</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-btn">
    <a href="?bttn=3" class="btn"> Get started</a>
</div>
```